# Login Script in 2.4.2 is not working

Tags: cakephp

I am new to cakephp. I have a problom while login. With wrong name and password redirects to login home page.

## UsersController.php

```
public function login() {
    $this->layout = 'admin-login';
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        if ($this->Auth->login($this->request->data)) {
            return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirectUrl())
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('Username or password is incorrect'), 'default', array(), 'auth');
        }
    }
}
```

## AppController.php

```
 public $components = array(
    'Session',
    'Auth' => array(
        'loginRedirect' => array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'index'),
        'logoutRedirect' => array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login'),
        'loginAction' => array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login')
    )
);

 public function beforeFilter() {
    $this->Auth->allow("login");
    //$this->Auth->authorize = array('Controller');
    $this->Auth->authenticate = array(
        'Form' => array (
            'scope'  => array(
                'User.is_active' => 1
            ) 
        )
    );   
}
public function isAuthorized($user) {
    return true;
}
```

## login.ctp

```
echo $this->Form->create('User');
echo $this->Form->input('username');
echo $this->Form->input('password'); 
echo $this->Form->submit(__('Submit');
echo $this->Form->end();
```

When i fill the wrong username & password & click on submit button it redirect to home page, Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You are using `AuthComponent::login()` wrong, you are only supposed to pass data to it in case you want to manually login a user, ie without automatic authentication.

If you want to use the components authentication functionality just call `$this->Auth->login()`

See also: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html#identifying-users-and-logging-them-in

> In 2.x `$this->Auth->login($this->request->data)` will log the user in with whatever data is posted, whereas in 1.3 `$this->Auth->login($this->data)` would try to identify the user first and only log in when successful.

Answer (score -1):

```
usercontroller

public function beforeFilter() {
        parent::beforeFilter();
        $this->Auth->allow('login','logout');
    }



public function login()
    {
       $this->layout= 'login';

       if ($this->request->is('post')) {

            if ($this->Auth->login()) {

                        $this->redirect('/users');
                        else {

                $this->Session->setFlash(__('Invalid email or password, please try again'));

            }
        }
        else{
            if($this->Auth->loggedIn())
                $this->redirect('index');
        }
    }
}
```

AppController

```
class AppController extends Controller {

public $components = array(

    'Session',
    'Auth' => array(
        'authenticate' => array(
            'Form' => array( 
                'userModel' => 'User',
                 'fields' => array(
                    'username' => 'user_name',
                    'password' => 'password'
                    )
                )
            ),
        'loginAction' => array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login'),
                    'loginRedirect' => array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'dashboard'),
        'logoutRedirect' => array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login'),
        'authError' => 'You don\'t have access here.',
                /*
                'loginAction' => array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'forgot_password'),
                'loginRedirect' => array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'dashboard'),
                'logoutRedirect' => array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'forgot_password'),
                'authError' => 'You don\'t have access here.',
                */
        ),

);
```

Comment: thanks jessica. But it is still not working. It redirect to login page  & also not displaying me any error message.