# User doesn't have user id after login

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.5

I can log in a user using `Auth->login($this->data)`. Debugging the `Auth->user()` after login all I see is the username and password. Is the Id supposed to be auto populated or do I need a way to manually set it? By going off a few tutorials it seem like the ID should already be there.

What is debugged:

```
\app\Controller\UsersController.php (line 90)
array(
    'User' => array(
        'password' => '*****',
        'username' => 'LittleRy'
    )
)
```

As ndm comment, I changed the call to `Auth->login()` so it should be grabbing the request info. With this change `login()` is always returning false. Below is the login form. I believe everything is being passed in correctly.

```
<div class="users form">
<?php echo $this->Session->Flash('auth');
     ?>
<?php echo $this->Form->create('User'); ?>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>
            <?php echo __('Please enter your username and password'); ?>
        </legend>
        <?php echo $this->Form->input('username');
        echo $this->Form->input('password');
    ?>
    </fieldset>
<?php echo $this->Form->end(__('Login')); ?>
</div>
```

Comment: **http://stackoverflow.com/a/19970731/1392379**

Comment: @ndm made the suggested changes, got bigger issues now

Comment: There are dozens of possible reasons for this. Wrong column type/length, passwords aren't stored hashed, the configured model/field names do not match the model/field names used in the view template, etc... Without all the code and context (controller action, component configuration, model schema + data, debugging results like the issued queries, ...) required to reproduce the problem, I'm afraid that you won't get much help.

Comment: What I thought, thanks for the help with the first part though anyway. Back to the tutorial we go!!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Login Script in 2.4.2 is not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19970556/login-script-in-2-4-2-is-not-working)

Answer (score 0):

try this $this->Auth->user('id'); to get user id.